# How to make it so a certain sound (like a guitar string being strung) makes a button be pressed

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, audio, i3, input

I am wondering if it is possible to make it so if a guitar string or such is strung a button is pressed, I am on arch linux using xorg and i3 as window  manager

Comment: Use https://github.com/zevv/bucklespring as source.